# micro services call through restTemplate, transaction rollback

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate, rpc

I have two micro services A B, In service A, call service B through restTemplate, and service B does some persistence job, like insert data into db.

**Here is my question**: what if service B execute successfully, data are saved into db, but timeout happen when service B response, so service A‘s API response fails, but data are actually inserted into db, how to rollback transaction?

Sqmple code:

```
@Service
public class ServiceA {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping("/user/save")
    public User saveUser(){
        ResponseEntity<User> entity = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://{serviceBHost}/insertData", User.class);
        return entity.getBody();
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class ServiceB {
    @AutoWired
    UserMapper userMapper;

    public User saveUser(User u) {
        User result = userMapper.insert(u);
        return result;
    }
}
```

[process flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKCB9.png)

Comment: Use plsql block for that.

Comment: can you explain in detai? I want to implement in code. thx

Answer (score 0):

Its not recommended to have distributed transaction in microservice based architecture. It should be avoided as much as possible.

Nevertheless, below article may be helpful to you.
https://walkingtreetech.medium.com/transaction-management-in-microservices-ab09b0cb803b